# select statement that skips certain rows

Tags: php, sql, database, t-sql

I need to select data from two tables. However there are two columns, where if one or both rows read NO,  I want to skip it.

Table 1

```
a--b--c-
1  r  l
2  t  f
3  d  c
```

Table 2

```
d--e--f--g-
1  r NO NO
2  r YES NO
3  r YES YES
```

QUERY:

```
 SELECT
    talbe1.a,
    table1.b,
    table1.c,
    table2.d,
    table2.e,
    table2.f,
    table2.g,
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
    table2 on table1.b = table2.e
    WHERE 'no' NOT IN (SELECT table2.f, table2.g FROM table2)
```

Comment: Why not just `WHERE f != "no" OR g != "no"`?

Comment: @kerrek - he needs `AND` not `OR` I think....

Comment: People sure are hungry for questions. 2 minutes, 10 answers + the one i didn't post

Comment: @JNK: Right, OP said "if one or both are NO" -- I misread that! It should be `WHERE f != "NO" AND g != "NO"`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    talbe1.a,
    table1.b,
    table1.c,
    table2.d,
    table2.e,
    table2.f,
    table2.g,
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
    table2 on table1.b = table2.e
        //if any of the f or g are not eqaul to "NO" only then select the result
        WHERE (table2.f != 'NO' AND table2.g != 'NO')

does not return if 
f = no and g = no
f = no and g = yes
f = yes and g = no

does return if
f = yes and g = yes
```

Comment: The questions/answers need to be edited.  I can edit them if you like.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Thank you. I should have checked the question more than once before going on about it. But, thanks again for the guidance towards the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Should be as simple as this:

```
  SELECT
    talbe1.a,
    table1.b,
    table1.c,
    table2.d,
    table2.e,
    table2.f,
    table2.g,
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
        table2 on table1.b = table2.e
  WHERE table2.f <> 'NO' AND table2.g <> 'NO'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  table1.a,
  table1.b,
  table1.c,
  table2.d,
  table2.e,
  table2.f,
  table2.g,
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.b = table2.e
WHERE table2.f <> 'NO' AND table2.g <> 'NO'
```

Also not sure about the structure of your tables, but is there a reason you're joining on table1.b = table2.e?

Answer (score 2):

Why not say that f=g and g='YES'?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WHERE (table2.f <> 'no' AND table2.g <> 'no')
```

Comment: No it shouldn't.  It should be OR.  If the statement was for the yes then it would be AND - WHERE table2.f = 'yes' AND table2.g = 'yes'

Comment: No, it's both.  He wants only rows where **BOTH** are `YES`

Comment: @JNK he wants rows where both are yes AND he does not want rows where one is yes and the other is no, which your solution fails to omit.

Comment: if he needs both 'yes' why write '<> no' and not '= yes'. Negative select should be avoided for legibility is a positive select exists

Answer (score -2):

You have to Use `LEFT JOIN` not `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    talbe1.a,
    table1.b,
    table1.c,
    table2.d,
    table2.e,
    table2.f,
    table2.g,
  FROM table1 LEFT JOIN 
        table2 on table1.b = table2.e
WHERE table2.f <> 'NO' AND table2.g <> 'NO'
```

Comment: Why do you think he needs a `LEFT` instead of an `INNER`?

Comment: Bcz he fetch datas from 2 tables!

Comment: How does that mean he should use a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: If JOIN clause statement failed no records returned in inner join but if Use Left Join Record returned by empty value for table2